# Is there any design pattern for multi-action method performing changes to a single object?

Tags: php, symfony

Let me explain what I mean:

```
function hugeAction(...) {
   ... perform sub-action 1
   ... perform sub-action 2
   ... perform sub-action 3
   ... perform sub-action 4
   ... perform sub-action 5
}
```

All the actions are performed with some `Object`, but can be placed in different functions. The order of the first 2-3 methods does matter, the order of remained methods - doesn't matter. If I leave all the code in a single place I'll get a huge and quite hard for maintenance function with not a simple process logic.

Currently I am using the solution with 2 primary actions in a `hugeAction(...)` + event subscriber for performing remained actions in another part of my application where all subscribers *live*.

Example:

```
function hugeAction(...) {
  ... perform action 1
  ... perform action 2
  ... dispatch event XXX
}

class SubscriberXXX extends YYY {
  function performHugeActionPart3() { ... }
  function performHugeActionPart4() { ... }
  function performHugeActionPart5() { ... }
}
```

What I am afraid of is that after a while this solution will hit me back... any changes to subscriber or additional action added will bring me in situation where I need to remember all the structure of the system and how the `hugeAction()` perfomes and processes one single `Object`.

Let me also mention that all these actions are not related to `Factory` / `Builder`-patterns, these actions *help* the main `Object` transition from state A to state B (example: add system comment, add system payment transaction, change project status, send notification, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if exactly design pattern, but my solution will be close to yours.

I will define new class service `PerfomHugeActionService`, I this part happens "core logic", which transition (I like to use [Symfony workflow component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/workflow.html) for this). Here we perform change of state from A to B, before/after this transition we fire new Event and we use subscriber to do all required side effects (add comment, add payment transaction ...).

With this you can easily add any variation of side effects / make it into queue and process in background etc.

For running order - You can have "priority" for your events which will make it in orders, solving first 2 actions. [Symfony EventDispatcher already supports priority for events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html).

Comment: Thank you for taking time answering my question. Another thing I am afraid of using `EventDispatcher` - event propagation. What if some time later I need more subscribers to this event and one of the subscribers will `stop Propagation`? This will definitely affect the rest of methods in subscribers.

Comment: If you stop propagation, then your subscriber is explicitly saying not to run anything. In that case its responsibility of that subscriber. Its the same as if in your command one part of action returned out before letting other run. Still will be responsibility of that action.

Comment: Is there any way to stop a single `Subscriber` with 4-5 methods, but allow another `Subscriber` to perform it's methods?

Comment: Once you return from subscriber function for example `onCompleteOrder` then this function get returned, but event dispatching will continue. In fact you can imagine dispatched events like subaction1, subaction2, ... if you return hard from one of these then execution wouldn't continue as well.

Comment: what do you mean by `hard return`?

Comment: For example you checking each subsection if it succeed if not you end processing.